# Adding hamburger menu and share buttons to websites

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, hamburger-menu

I'm building my own website as well as studying Web Development and I have questions for experienced devs.

Firstly I want to add a hamburger menu to my website to click and visit other pages and but not sure how to do it. Found some handy codes and tried to add them to my main HTML and CSS files but it didn't work. Do I need to create whole different HTML/CSS/JS files for the menu and then link them to the main ones? Or what is the solution?

Few examples I can use: `https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/VLjKMQ/` `https://codepen.io/netfuel/pen/rIlnB/` `https://codepen.io/sergioandrade/pen/onkub`

My second question is that I added share buttons to my website through Add To Any. Twitter and WhatsApp buttons work pretty well but Facebook doesn't (see in the 1st ss). href code is `href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"` My website is not online yet. Can that cause an error?

Also I want to make buttons smaller and responsive (see in the 2nd ss). I tried `style="font-size: .. ;"` so far but didn't work.

Thank you.

[image: SS1]
[image: SS2]

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do all your CSS styling inside a single CSS file. No need to create a new one.

Also, your website does not need to be online in order to link externally to another site (your facebook link).

It's hard to tell what's causing you problems. Can you share your code? There could be some styling from eg. `<body>` that's interfering with your menu. As for sizing your buttons, try using simple width & height. But again, it's much easier to help you if you share your code.

Try pasting it into a jsfiddle.net document. It's super simple and effective to work with for sharing code online!

Edit:

Don't use `style` in your HTML, use your CSS file for that. Makes for some much cleaner code that is much easier to work with in the long run.

To make the icons bigger:

CSS:

```
.a2a_button_facebook, .a2a_button_twitter, .a2a_button_whatsapp {
/* change this, it's just a demo height */
 width: 500px !important;

/* change this, it's just a demo height */
 height: 500px !important;
```

I am not sure if `!important` is necessary, as I haven't used AddToAny before. But if it has styling inside its own library, the `!important` rule is used to overwrite that.

All the codepens you have linked are fancy and all, but they each have hundreds of lines of code that I'd have to look through to find out why they don't work. I study Web Development as well and I can tell you for a fact that you will learn much more from simply coding basic HTML & CSS in the beginning instead of pasting multiple hundred lines of codes into your files and get help to debug them online.

I've made a very simple navigation bar for you to get you started:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmk6qa7h/

What I put in:

HTML:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link 1">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link 2">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="link 3">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="link 4">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

This is the correct semantic way to set up a navigation bar. The `<nav>` element matters!

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 100px;
}
```

`.navbar a` **padding** will determine the space between the elements. **Width** is of course the size of each element. Play around with it a little bit. Let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Thank you. These are codes of my Homepage where I want to put the menu on. Unfortunately the background image didn't loaded. https://jsfiddle.net/rumeysagelgi/yf3qgep2/2/

Comment: Also this is the code of share buttons. Adjusting width&height didn't work either.        `<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
              <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style" style="float: right;">
              <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
              <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
              <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
              <a class="a2a_button_whatsapp"></a>
              </div>
              <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
            <!-- AddToAny END -->
        `

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help and tips! The menu code you wrote looks fine and I think I need to work on and develop it a bit more. By the way I removed AddToAny code and put the original FB/TW share button codes instead (also styled in css) using Facebook for Devs/Twitter for Devs as they look so much better and responsive. Twitter works well again. However when I click the FB button it shares their Developers Page, not my Page. I added another screenshot to my post. Any opinions on that?

Comment: This is the code FB gave me for the button: `<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button&size=small&width=67&height=20&appId" width="67" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>`